# Interactive Brokers - I keep getting invalid consumer while requesting OAuth token

Tags: c#, .net, rest, httpclient, interactive-brokers

I have a valid consumer key and I'm unable to get Interactive Brokers Web API OAuth to work.

> {"error":"id: 3931, error: invalid consumer","statusCode":401}

- The endpoint I'm trying to get to work: [https://www.interactivebrokers.com/webtradingapi/doc.html#tag/OAuth/paths/~1oauth~1request_token/post](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/webtradingapi/doc.html#tag/OAuth/paths/%7E1oauth%7E1request_token/post)
- OAuth v1.0a specification https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#auth_header_authorization

Am I missing something in my implementation?

It's also on [GitHub](https://github.com/Hulkstance/interactive-brokers-oauth).

```cs
var httpClient = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.interactivebrokers.com/tradingapi/v1/")
};

var restClient = new IBRestClient(httpClient);
var response = await restClient.RequestTokenAsync("xxxxx");

Console.WriteLine($"Response: {response}");

Console.ReadLine();

public sealed class IBRestClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public IBRestClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async ValueTask<string> RequestTokenAsync(string consumerKey)
    {
        const string requestUri = "oauth/request_token";

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri);

        var baseUrl = _httpClient.BaseAddress!.AbsoluteUri;
        var authorizationHeader = OAuthHelper.GetAuthorizationHeader($"{baseUrl}{requestUri}", "POST", consumerKey);

        var authSplit = authorizationHeader.Split(' ');
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(authSplit[0], authSplit[1]);

        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

```cs
public static class OAuthHelper
{
    private static readonly RandomNumberGenerator Random = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();

    public static string GetAuthorizationHeader(string uri, string method, string consumerKey)
    {
        var oauthParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "oauth_consumer_key", consumerKey },
            { "oauth_signature_method", "RSA-SHA256" },
            { "oauth_timestamp", GetTimestamp() },
            { "oauth_nonce", GetNonce() },
            { "oauth_callback", "oob" }
        };

        // The request parameters are collected, sorted and concatenated into a normalized string
        var queryParameters = ExtractQueryParams(uri);
        var oauthParamString = GetOAuthParamString(queryParameters, oauthParameters);
        var baseUri = GetBaseUriString(uri);

        // Signature Base String
        var signatureBaseString = GetSignatureBaseString(baseUri, method, oauthParamString);

        var pem = File.ReadAllText("private_encryption.pem");
        var signingKey = RSA.Create();
        signingKey.ImportFromPem(pem);

        var signature = SignSignatureBaseString(signatureBaseString, Encoding.UTF8, signingKey);
        oauthParameters.Add("oauth_signature", signature);

        // Constructs and returns the Authorization header
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var param in oauthParameters)
        {
            sb
                .Append(sb.Length == 0 ? "OAuth " : ",")
                .Append(param.Key)
                .Append("=\"")
                .Append(ToUriRfc3986(param.Value))
                .Append('"');
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Parse query parameters out of the URL.
    /// </summary>
    private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> ExtractQueryParams(string uri)
    {
        var queryParamCollection = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        var beginIndex = uri.IndexOf('?');
        if (beginIndex <= 0)
        {
            return queryParamCollection;
        }

        var rawQueryString = uri[beginIndex..];
        var decodedQueryString = Uri.UnescapeDataString(rawQueryString);
        var mustEncode = !decodedQueryString.Equals(rawQueryString);

        var queryParams = rawQueryString.Split('&', '?');
        foreach (var queryParam in queryParams)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryParam))
            {
                continue;
            }

            var separatorIndex = queryParam.IndexOf('=');
            var key = separatorIndex < 0 ? queryParam : Uri.UnescapeDataString(queryParam[..separatorIndex]);
            var value = separatorIndex < 0
                ? string.Empty
                : Uri.UnescapeDataString(queryParam[(separatorIndex + 1)..]);
            var encodedKey = mustEncode ? ToUriRfc3986(key) : key;
            var encodedValue = mustEncode ? ToUriRfc3986(value) : value;

            if (!queryParamCollection.ContainsKey(encodedKey))
            {
                queryParamCollection[encodedKey] = new List<string>();
            }

            queryParamCollection[encodedKey].Add(encodedValue);
        }

        return queryParamCollection;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Lexicographically sorts all parameters and concatenates them into a string.
    /// </summary>
    private static string GetOAuthParamString(IDictionary<string, List<string>> queryParameters,
        IDictionary<string, string> oauthParameters)
    {
        var sortedParameters = new SortedDictionary<string, List<string>>(queryParameters, StringComparer.Ordinal);
        foreach (var oauthParameter in oauthParameters)
        {
            sortedParameters[oauthParameter.Key] = new List<string> { oauthParameter.Value };
        }

        // Build the OAuth parameter string
        var parameterString = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var parameter in sortedParameters)
        {
            var values = parameter.Value;
            values.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal); // Keys with same name are sorted by their values
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                parameterString
                    .Append(parameterString.Length > 0 ? "&" : string.Empty)
                    .Append(parameter.Key)
                    .Append('=')
                    .Append(value);
            }
        }

        return parameterString.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Normalizes the URL.
    /// </summary>
    private static string GetBaseUriString(string uriString)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(uriString);
        var lowerCaseScheme = uri.Scheme.ToLower();
        var lowerCaseAuthority = uri.Authority.ToLower();
        var path = uri.AbsolutePath;

        if (("http".Equals(lowerCaseScheme) && uri.Port == 80) || ("https".Equals(lowerCaseScheme) && uri.Port == 443))
        {
            // Remove port if it matches the default for scheme
            var index = lowerCaseAuthority.LastIndexOf(':');
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                lowerCaseAuthority = lowerCaseAuthority[..index];
            }
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            path = "/";
        }

        return $"{lowerCaseScheme}://{lowerCaseAuthority}{path}"; // Remove query and fragment
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The Signature Base String is a consistent reproducible concatenation of the request elements into a single string.
    /// </summary>
    private static string GetSignatureBaseString(string baseUri, string httpMethod, string oauthParamString)
    {
        return httpMethod.ToUpper() // Uppercase HTTP method
               + "&" + ToUriRfc3986(baseUri) // Base URI
               + "&" + ToUriRfc3986(oauthParamString); // OAuth parameter string
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Signs the signature base string using an RSA private key.
    /// </summary>
    private static string SignSignatureBaseString(string baseString, Encoding encoding, RSA privateKey)
    {
        var hash = Sha256Digest(baseString, encoding);
        var signedHashValue = privateKey.SignHash(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signedHashValue);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Percent encodes entities.
    /// </summary>
    private static string ToUriRfc3986(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            return input;
        }

        var escaped = new StringBuilder(Uri.EscapeDataString(input));
        string[] uriRfc3986EscapedChars = { "!", "*", "'", "(", ")" };
        foreach (var escapedChar in uriRfc3986EscapedChars)
        {
            escaped.Replace(escapedChar, UriHelper.HexEscape(escapedChar[0]));
        }

        return escaped.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns a cryptographic hash of the given input.
    /// </summary>
    private static byte[] Sha256Digest(string input, Encoding encoding)
    {
        var inputBytes = encoding.GetBytes(input);
        return SHA256.HashData(inputBytes);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Generates a 16 char random string for replay protection.
    /// </summary>
    private static string GetNonce()
    {
        var data = new byte[8];
        Random.GetBytes(data);
        return BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns UNIX Timestamp.
    /// </summary>
    private static string GetTimestamp()
    {
        return DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString();
    }
}

internal static class UriHelper
{
    private static readonly char[] HexUpperChars =
    {
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'
    };

    internal static string HexEscape(char character)
    {
        if (character > '\xff')
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(character));
        }

        var chars = new char[3];
        var pos = 0;
        EscapeAsciiChar(character, chars, ref pos);
        return new string(chars);
    }

    private static void EscapeAsciiChar(char ch, char[] to, ref int pos)
    {
        to[pos++] = '%';
        to[pos++] = HexUpperChars[(ch & 0xf0) >> 4];
        to[pos++] = HexUpperChars[ch & 0xf];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm facing exactly the same issue

Comment: @Aldridge1991, no. It doesn't work on their end. Don't waste your time on it

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I think as well.

Comment: I am trying to port their Python example to C#, but failing to success with RSA-SHA256 signature, their generate_rsa_sha_256_signature gives different result comparting to c# RSA.SignData ... (mine is very similar to yours)